# How to get a date out of UNIX timestamp with javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, unix-timestamp

Here's my jsfidde: http://jsfiddle.net/9SUqX/74/

Original Code:

```
var comments = [
    {name:"Full Name",comment:"Quote",timestamp:1332045720},
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul#feed").append("<li>\
    <blockquote>"+comments[0].comment+"</blo‌ckquote>\
    <cite>-"+comments[0].name+", "+comments[0].timestamp+" </cite>\
    </li>");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to multiply the timestamp by 1000 (Javascript uses milliseconds) and pass it to Date:

```
var comments = [
    {name:"Full Name",comment:"Quote",timestamp:1332045720},
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    var d = new Date(comments[0].timestamp * 1000);
    var date = [(d.getMonth() + 1), d.getDate(), d.getFullYear()].join("/");
    $("ul#feed").append("<li>\
    <blockquote>"+comments[0].comment+"</blo‌ckquote>\
    <cite>-"+comments[0].name+", "+date+" </cite>\
    </li>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot. One more question though, is there a way to get just the month/date/year from the way this?

Comment: @cam424, just edited it for that.

Comment: You are a star! Thank you!